# check the key has value or not in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
const sampleObj = {
    yearOne: [],
    yearTwo:[{name:"test1", age: "26"}],
    yearThree:[],
    yearFour:[{name:"test3", age: "23"}]
}
```

the above one is my sample object i need to remove all empty key value from the object. i tried with this code, got from internet

```
const filterObj = Object.keys(sampleObj).forEach(key =>
    (sampleObj[key] && typeof sampleObj[key] === 'object') && delete sampleObj[key]);
```

but not working for me. I am getting the fliterObj is `undefined` how to fix this.

I need to print my `filterObj` should be like this

```
{
    yearTwo:[{name:"test1", age: "26"}],
    yearFour:[{name:"test3", age: "23"}]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `reduce` method and check if array has any elements in it.

```js
const sampleObj = {yearOne: [],yearTwo:[{name:"test1", age: "26"}],yearThree:[],yearFour:[{name:"test3", age: "23"}]}

const filterObj = Object.entries(sampleObj)
  .reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
    if (v.length) r[k] = v;
    return r;
  }, {})

console.log(filterObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

> check the key has value or not in javascript

I should note that **all** of the properties in your example object have values: They all contain references to arrays. A couple of those arrays are empty, though, which I presume are the ones you want to remove/exclude.

> I am getting the fliterObj is undefined how to fix this.

`forEach` always returns `undefined`.

Since your code is *modifying* the object, you don't need to use that return value. But the logic is a bit off (it deletes any property with a truthy value), and you're probably better off creating a new object instead (since `delete` de-optimizes the object).

The simple way is with a loop, perhaps using `Object.entries` (which is easily polyfilled for older environments when necessary):

```
const filteredObj = {};
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(sampleObj)) {
    if (value && (!Array.isArray(value) || value.length)) {
        filteredObj[key] = value;
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const sampleObj = {
    yearOne: [],
    yearTwo:[{name:"test1", age: "26"}],
    yearThree:[],
    yearFour:[{name:"test3", age: "23"}]
};
const filteredObj = {};
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(sampleObj)) {
    if (value && (!Array.isArray(value) || value.length)) {
        filteredObj[key] = value;
    }
}
console.log(filteredObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

But it's possible to shoehorn that into a `reduce` call if you like (because any array operation can be shoehorned into a `reduce` call):

```
const sampleObj = {
    yearOne: [],
    yearTwo:[{name:"test1", age: "26"}],
    yearThree:[],
    yearFour:[{name:"test3", age: "23"}]
};
const filteredObj = Object.keys(sampleObj).reduce((obj, key) => {
    const value = sampleObj[key];
    if (value && (!Array.isArray(value) || value.length)) {
        obj[key] = value;
    }
    return obj;
}, {});
```

Live Example:

```js
const sampleObj = {
    yearOne: [],
    yearTwo:[{name:"test1", age: "26"}],
    yearThree:[],
    yearFour:[{name:"test3", age: "23"}]
};
const filteredObj = Object.keys(sampleObj).reduce((obj, key) => {
    const value = sampleObj[key];
    if (value && (!Array.isArray(value) || value.length)) {
        obj[key] = value;
    }
    return obj;
}, {});
console.log(filteredObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

It doesn't buy you anything, though.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this**

```js
const sampleObj = {
    yearOne: [],
    yearTwo:[{name:"test1", age: "26"}],
    yearThree:[],
    yearFour:[{name:"test3", age: "23"}]
}

Object.keys(sampleObj).map(e=>{
  if(sampleObj[e] && sampleObj[e].length === 0){
    delete sampleObj[e]
  }
})

console.log(sampleObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

forEach does not return result. It iterates over original instance. I fixed your code like below.

```js
 const sampleObj = {
        yearOne: [],
        yearTwo:[{name:"test1", age: "26"}],
        yearThree:[],
        yearFour:[{name:"test3", age: "23"}]
    }

    Object.keys(sampleObj).forEach(key => {
       if (sampleObj[key].length == 0) 
           delete sampleObj[key];
    });
    
    
    console.log(sampleObj);
```